# Правописание однокоренных слов

Tags: грамматика, однокоренные-слова

Почему в прилагательном **меридиональный** присутствует буква **о**, а существительном **меридиан** - **а**?

Comment: @Булат, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 4):

Меридиональный происходит от латинского прилагательного "meridionalis".

Comment: Это как экстрим и экстремальный?